# Angular Animation leave transition not working on ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-animations

In Angular 7 I am working on an animated expansion panel. I use the state enter to change the opacity from 0 to 1 and height 0 to *. On leave I want the opacity to go from 1 to 0 and height from * to 0.

I've can successfully do the animation for enter but for some reason i get a funny result on leave. It almost expands first and then contracts. I've setup a stackblitz example to better explain.

How do I get the result when expanded and the button click me is clicked the opacity to go from 1 to 0 and height from * to 0?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bkarvangula?embed=1&file=app/expansion-steps-example.ts)

My animation code below. Thanks in advance!

```
animations: [
    trigger('myAccordian', [      
      state('*', style({ opacity: 1, height: '*'})),
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0, height: 0}),
        animate('1s ease-in')
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({ opacity: 0, height: 0}),
        animate('1s ease-out')
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you describe a '*' state - then you also need to provide some informations about how it should look in the *void* state. Alternative is to directly describe the output style and then inside the animation handle the finish style. A good example can be found here: [Angular transition](https://angular.io/api/animations/transition)

```js
trigger('myAccordian', [      
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0, height: 0}),
    animate('1s ease-in', style({ opacity: 1, height: '*' }))
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    style({ opacity: 1, height: '*'}),
    animate('1s ease-out', style({ opacity: 0, height: 0 }))
  ])
])
```